Нужна ли запятая после "согласился" в данном предложении?
Хорошенько подумав, я согласился(?) и в том же месяце был принят на работу.
И доп. вопрос: ставится ли запятая между сказуемыми, выраженными одно активным, а другое страдательным залогом?

Правильно:
Хорошенько подумав, я согласился и в том же месяце был принят на работу.
Пояснение
Сомнения в однородности сказуемых, выраженных различным образом возникают часто, но ответ может быть только таким. Однородность — это понятия синтаксиса и поэтому не зависит от морфологической формы однородных членов.
Однородными считаются члены предложения, которые в предложении относятся к одному и тому же слову и являются одним и тем же членом предложения. Однородные сказуемые относятся к одному подлежащему и отвечают на общий вопрос: что говорится о его действии или состоянии.
Однородные сказуемые
Сказуемые могут выражаться не только глаголами, но и 
прилагательными, краткими причастиями, существительными и 
так далее. Рассмотрим, например, такое предложение:
“Книга приобретена и уже читается”.
Сказуемые выражены одно причастием, а другое – глаголом. Это 
не мешает им быть однородными.
Еще такой пример: “Ночь была тиха и наполнена шорохами 
леса”. Здесь однородные сказуемые выражены прилагательным и 
причастием.

